# pandas condensing multiple columns for same value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to integrate multiple data sources and I'm finding it a bit tricky to concisely combine my columns.  I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Address Data','City data','State Data', 'Zip Data', np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
     [ np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Address Data','City data','State Data', 'Zip Data',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                  [ np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Address Data','City data','State Data', 'Zip Data']],
                 columns = ['Address1','City1','State1','Zip1','Address2','City2','State2','Zip2','Address3','City3','State3','Zip3'])

print df

       Address1      City1      State1      Zip1      Address2      City2/  
0  Address Data  City Data  State Data  Zip Data           NaN        NaN   
1           NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN  Address Data  City Data   
2           NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN   

       State2      Zip2      Address3      City3      State3      Zip3  
0         NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN  
1  State Data  Zip Data           NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN  
2         NaN       NaN  Address Data  City Data  State Data  Zip Data
```

I'm trying to combine to something like this:

```
#run code here to combine multiple versions of the columns

print df

   Address       City       State       Zip
0  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
1  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
2  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
```

I was hoping I could use lines like this to set multiple columns at once:

```
df.loc[df['State1'].notnull(),['Address','city','state','State','Zip']] = df.loc[df['State1'].notnull(),['Address1','City1','State1','Zip1']].values
```

However, .loc doesn't allow you to create multiple columns at once.  Any thoughts on how to combine the data would be much appreciated!

**Edit based on solution below**

The problem with that solution is my data may actually look more like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Address Data','City data','State Data', 'Zip Data', 'Address Data','City data','State Data', 'Zip Data',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
 [ np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Address Data','City data','State Data', 'Zip Data',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
              [ np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Address Data','City data','State Data', 'Zip Data']],
             columns = ['Address1','City1','State1','Zip1','Address2','City2','State2','Zip2','Address3','City3','State3','Zip3'])
```

In this case, the soltuion below gives me 4 rows, when I only want the original 3.  What I want to say is "if section 1 has data, use section 1, else if section 2 has data use section 2, else if section 3 has data, use section 3".  Each row needs to remain unique, because there are many other attributes of a row that I am not consolidating.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think solution is totally different, so I decide create new answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#random dataframe
np.random.seed(1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,9)))
df1.columns = ['a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3']

df1.loc[[1,2],['a1','b1','c1']] = np.nan
print (df1)
    a1   b1   c1  a2  b2  c2  a3  b3  c3
0  5.0  8.0  9.0   5   0   0   1   7   6
1  NaN  NaN  NaN   5   2   4   2   4   7
2  NaN  NaN  NaN   7   0   6   9   9   7

#stack dataframe and extract string and numbers from column e
df = df1.stack().reset_index()
df.columns= ['d','e','f']
df[['g','h']] = df.e.str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)', expand=True)

#append 1 to d, because index starts from 1 and compare with h
df = df[df.d + 1 == df.h.astype(int)]
#remove columns h, e
df = df.drop(['h', 'e'], axis=1)
#reshaping
df = df.pivot(index='d', columns='g', values='f')
#remove index and columns names (pandas 0.18.0+)
df = df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print (df)
     a    b    c
0  5.0  8.0  9.0
1  5.0  2.0  4.0
2  9.0  9.0  7.0
```

EDIT: I try modify a bit your sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Address Data1','City data1','State Data1', 'Zip Data1', 'Address Data2','City data2','State Data2', 'Zip Data2',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
 [ np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Address Data3','City data3','State Data3', 'Zip Data3',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
              [ np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Address Data4','City data4','State Data4', 'Zip Data4']],
             columns = ['Address1','City1','State1','Zip1','Address2','City2','State2','Zip2','Address3','City3','State3','Zip3'])

print (df1)
        Address1       City1       State1       Zip1       Address2  \
0  Address Data1  City data1  State Data1  Zip Data1  Address Data2   
1            NaN         NaN          NaN        NaN  Address Data3   
2            NaN         NaN          NaN        NaN            NaN   

        City2       State2       Zip2       Address3       City3       State3  \
0  City data2  State Data2  Zip Data2            NaN         NaN          NaN   
1  City data3  State Data3  Zip Data3            NaN         NaN          NaN   
2         NaN          NaN        NaN  Address Data4  City data4  State Data4   

        Zip3  
0        NaN  
1        NaN  
2  Zip Data4
```

```
#stack dataframe and extract string and numbers from column e
df = df1.stack().reset_index()
df.columns= ['d','e','f']
df[['g','h']] = df.e.str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)', expand=True)

#append 1 to d, because index starts from 1 and compare with h
df = df[df.d + 1 == df.h.astype(int)]
#remove columns h, e
df = df.drop(['h', 'e'], axis=1)
#reshaping
df = df.pivot(index='d', columns='g', values='f')

df = df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
         Address        City        State        Zip
0  Address Data1  City data1  State Data1  Zip Data1
1  Address Data3  City data3  State Data3  Zip Data3
2  Address Data4  City data4  State Data4  Zip Data4
```

Comment: Think there's a problem - when I run it errors out on :df[['g','h']] = df.e.str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)', expand=True).  Also, when I run the df1.stack().reset_index() on my sample df provided above, it doesn't transform anything.

Comment: What is version of your pandas? `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: 17.0 - I'll upgrade to 18.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I needed, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can first select column names by `list` comprehension and then use `pd.lreshape`:

```
a = ([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Address')])
c = ([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('City')])
s = ([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('State')])
z = ([col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Zip')])

print (a)
print (c)
print (s)
print (z)
['Address1', 'Address2', 'Address3']
['City1', 'City2', 'City3']
['State1', 'State2', 'State3']
['Zip1', 'Zip2', 'Zip3']

df1 = pd.lreshape(df, {'Address':a,  'City' :c, 'State':s,  'Zip' :z}) 
print (df1)

        Address       State       City       Zip
0  Address Data  State Data  City data  Zip Data
1  Address Data  State Data  City data  Zip Data
2  Address Data  State Data  City data  Zip Data
```

EDIT:

If you need **NOT** drop rows with `NaN` values, add parameter `dropna=False`:

```
df1 = pd.lreshape(df, {'Address':a,  'City' :c, 'State':s,  'Zip' :z}, dropna=False) 
print (df1)
        Address       State       City       Zip
0  Address Data  State Data  City data  Zip Data
1           NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN
2           NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN
3           NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN
4  Address Data  State Data  City data  Zip Data
5           NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN
6           NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN
7           NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN
8  Address Data  State Data  City data  Zip Data
```

Another numpy solution, but data can be nice ordered (in sample yes, in real maybe not):

```
print (pd.DataFrame((df.values.reshape(9,4)), columns=['Address','City','State','Zip'])
         .dropna())

        Address       City       State       Zip
0  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
4  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
8  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
```

Comment: Close, what happens here if there are multiple values?  For example, The "Address1" section may be fully filled out, and the "Address2" section would be filled out, but because "Address1" is filled out I want to take that.

Comment: I think parameter `dropna=False` can help you, see edit.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael see comments I added, I think the solution is missing a little - I want to keep 3 rows, because these fields only represent a small sample of the total data I have in each row.  If the data has 100 fields, I'm aggregating maybe 30 of them, so the end result would be 80 fields.

Comment: So first row from `Address2` to `Zip2` is omited in output?

Comment: Correct - if address1 exists, take that series of features, if address2 exists and address1 is null, take those, if 1 & 2 are null but 3 is there, take 3

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
uniq_cols = df.columns.str.replace(r'\d+$', '').unique()

new = pd.DataFrame(columns=uniq_cols)

for col in uniq_cols:
    new[col] = df.filter(like=col).apply(lambda x: x.dropna()[0], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
In [282]: new
Out[282]:
        Address       City       State       Zip
0  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
1  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
2  Address Data  City data  State Data  Zip Data
```

Explanation:

```
In [283]: uniq_cols
Out[283]: array(['Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'], dtype=object)

In [284]: df.filter(like='Address').apply(lambda x: x.dropna()[0], axis=1)
Out[284]:
0    Address Data
1    Address Data
2    Address Data
dtype: object
```

Comment: Partway there - doesn't handle cases where the second set of values have data.